# How to split a numpy array using a binary list?

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray

If I have a numpy array say

```
A = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]]
```

and a list

```
L = [1,0,1,1]
```

Is there a way to split A down axis0 based off of if they are a 1/0 in L? This would be my desired result:

```
A1 = [[1,2],[5,6],[7,8]]
A2 = [[3,4]]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `L` is binary, you can convert `L` to boolean type and then use [boolean indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing):

```
A = np.array([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6],[7,8]])
L = np.array([1,0,1,1])

L = L.astype(bool)
A1, A2 = A[L], A[~L]

A1
#array([[1, 2],
#       [5, 6],
#       [7, 8]])

A2
#array([[3, 4]])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I never knew about binary indexing, so this was very helpful.